# Can you give an example of a continuous function with this property?

Tags: analysis, functions

Can you give an example of a continuous function $f:[0, \infty)$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$
such as $\lim_{b\to \infty}$ $\int_0^b{f(x)dx}$ exists but $f$$\notin$ $L^{1}$ ([0, $\infty$)) ?

($f$$\notin$ $L^{1}$ ([0, $\infty$)) means that $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable in that interval)

Comment: The classic example is: $\lim_{b\to+\infty} \int_0^b \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ exists but not $\int_0^{+\infty} \left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| dx$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean `finitely exists` when you say `limit exists` (otherwise constant function works), an example is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x=0$}\\
\dfrac{\sin x}{x}&\text{if }x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This is a continuous function which is conditionally integrable on $\Bbb R^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the piecewise linear interpolation between the points $(n,0)$ and  $(n+\frac12,(-1)^n)$, both with $n\in\Bbb N_0$.
Then $\int_0^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ will behave like the alternating harmonic series and converge, whereas $\int |f|$ is like the normal harmonic series and diverges (both when taking the limit of Riemann over finite intervals and when taking the Lebesgue integral  directly).